# Если false делаем заново

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Вот к примеру у меня есть такой код:

```
function test() {
    $test[rand(0,100)];
    return $test;
}
```

мне нужно сделать так, допустим `$test[100]` не существует, а в рандоме выпало `100`, то если `empty($test[100])` что бы он делал всё заново.

Comment: а что за переменная $test ? она не задается же вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [while](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.while.php) или [goto](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.goto.php). Но я бы пересмотрел логику работы скрипта, расскажите чего хотите добиться.

Comment: Для этого есть функция [array_rand][1].
   [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-rand.php

    return array_rand($test);